# Propertie of the shift permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

Let $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $\sigma=(12...n)$, choose $k\in\{1,2,...,n\}$ then if $k|n$ and $r=\frac{n}{k}$ then
$$\sigma^k=\tau_1\tau_2...\tau_k$$ where each $\tau_i$ is a $r$-cycle.

Is this true? I kind of saw this fact from playing around with the shift operator and dont know how to prove it.

Comment: Yes it's true.  Interpret $\sigma$ as an operation on the additive group on integers mod $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine $n$ beads strung in a circle. If $k|n$ and you count around in steps of size $k$ you return in $n/k$ steps.

You should be able to guess the generalization for more general $k$. It involves the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Well if we fix $n$ and let $k<n$ then $\sigma^k=\tau_1\tau_2...\tau_{gcd(k,n)}$ and each $\tau_i$ is an $\frac{n}{gcd(k,n)}$-cycle. 
I think my problem is that I cant put what I see into something im content as a proof.
I tried using @saulspatz advice but it just made me more confused.